# How to change label text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, label

I try to change label text but nothing works

```
  function changeText(lblTxt) {

        var lblAjaxUpdate = $("#" + Key).find("[class='label']");//finds the label no problem

        lblAjaxUpdate.attr('text', lblTxt);// don't work
        lblAjaxUpdate.InnerText = lblTxt;//don't work
        lblAjaxUpdate.InnerHtml = lblTxt;//don't work
        lblAjaxUpdate.value = lblTxt;// and...don't work :(       
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ? do i miss something?

Comment: `lblAjaxUpdate.text('youText');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
lblAjaxUpdate.text(lblTxt);
```

You can also use InnerText on DOM object but not on jQuery object, use indexer or .get() to convert the jQuery object to DOM

```
lblAjaxUpdate[0].InnerText = lblTxt;
lblAjaxUpdate[0].InnerHtml = lblTxt;
```

OR

```
lblAjaxUpdate[0].get(0).InnerText = lblTxt;
lblAjaxUpdate[0]..get(0).InnerHtml = lblTxt;
```

Comment: Yes, I can see your attempts, being unlucky though to guess the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

in your case:

```
lblAjaxUpdate.text(lblTxt)
```

or

```
lblAjaxUpdate.get(0).InnerText = lblTxt
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic use with

```
$('label').text();
```

is shown here http://jsfiddle.net/aCQg9/